# checkbox в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В БД есть поле с типом данных varchar. 
Там разные значения будут, но нужно еще сделать checkbox, который бы отправлял - значения Yes/No или 0/1.

Вот такой checkbox

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox([], false); ?>
```

В правилах валидации rules() просто указан тип 'string'
При отправке , поле status отправляет null.
Скажите как правильно это реализовать, нужны дополнительные правила валидации?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(['uncheck'=>'No', 'value'=>'Yes'], false); ?>
```

В правилах проверяем на соответствие значение:

```
['status', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^(yes|no)$/', 'message' => 'Your message for error.'],
```

Comment: Не работает, нужно даже и без Yes, по простому - поле чекнули - 1 , не чекнули - 0, пока что так, что так дает null. Проблема еще в том, что в этом самом поле у меня будет и textInput, и checkbox и textarea

Comment: @VladShkuta Таааак, не может быть, тогда давайте больше иформации, как вы проверяете значение и смотрите ли во вкладку Network в браузере, когда отправляете форму